# Why doesn't Azure REST API to assign user role to a subscription work?

Tags: azure, rest, azure-resource-manager, azure-rest-api

I am trying to add a user role to a subscription in Azure using REST API following this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-rest#add-a-role-assignment).

1. I got a bearer token with my login and passed it as a header Authorization parameter.
2. Gave all the values as described in the doc
3. PFA REST API call I performed.

API response says below;

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "AuthenticationFailed",
    "message": "Authentication failed."
}
```

}

Please let me know if any one successfully used this API and performed operations. Also is there any Azure .NET API to this operation?

[REST API Postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6i4V.png)

Comment: Seems the token you obtained has no permission to perform this action. May I know how you get this token?

Comment: @StanleyGong  When I login to an Azure web app using my credentials I get a access token in network calls in the response. I copy pasted it to postman for Authorization parameter.

Comment: I see, if so ,it means you have no permission to assign roles to your subscription. Pls ask your subscription admin to assign a azure subscription role ,i,e contributor to you.

Comment: I have UAA permissions to the subscription

Comment: Click `Try it` in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/roleassignments/create), login your account and call the api directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means your user account does not have the permission to create the role assignment, specifically `Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write`.

To solve the issue, you need to ask the admin who is the `Owner` or `User Access Administrator`(or [custom RBAC role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles) with `Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write` permission) of your subscription to assign the `Owner` or `User Access Administrator` or custom role with the permission above for you at the subscription scope first, follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal), then get a new token, you will be able to assign the role to others like the admin assign the role to you i.e. create role assignment.

**Update:**

If you want to get the access token via your user credential, you could use the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow), please follow the steps below.

1.In your App registration, add the `user_impersonation` Delegated permission of `Azure Service Management` API.

[image]

2.Hit the URL below in the browser, change the `tenant-id`, `client-id`, `redirect_uri` to yours, login your user account.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-id/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=xxxxxxxx
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http://localhost
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://management.azure.com/.default
&state=12345
```

Then you will get a code like below, copy it.

[image]

Don't forget to remove the state and session_state.

[image]

3.In the postman, use the query below, then you can get the token.

[image]